# Is it possible to keep the Webview having same session from Parse SDK when the user is logged in using it

Tags: android, session, parse-platform

I'm building an new android app using parse.com
Users can login to a parse app.
This parse app has hosting web page showing user's contents.
I want to show the webpage using an Webview.
so the webview need to login or share the session from Parse SDK automatically.

I used to develop this feature by sharing cookies between the Network Client instance and Webview.

It's hard to figure out how to do this in Parse system, since I can't see the mechanism how the Parse Android SDK works about session managing and there is no Info about this in the official documents.

Thanks for your help in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by myself and made it an open source on github.

https://github.com/ryuheechul/ParseSessionSync